# what is the javascript equivalent for vbscript "window.onBeforeUnload = Nothing"

Tags: javascript, vbscript

```
window.onBeforeUnload = Nothing
```

What is the JavaScript equivalent for the above vbscript statement?

Comment: I think that it is just window.unLoad.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = null;`, `window.onbeforeunload = undefined;`,  or `window.onbeforeunload = function () { };` should all work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Should do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `window.onBeforeUnload = function() {}` do the same thing?

If we set it to null, it results in javascript error.

Comment: If you want to call window.onbeforeunload() when you assign it to null, it causes an exception.

Comment: Yes, of course it would. You've set it null. window.onbeforeunload is a box you can drop a function in for something else to use. Or you can set it to null to displace a function that was in there. Name the handler if you want to use it manually. e.g. `window.onbeforeonload=someHandler; someHandler();` In most cases with JavaScript, there is nothing magic about the assignment operator. You're just attaching something to a property or var and functions are things that can be attached like any other value. Exceptions are cookies and setter properties (which will be rare for now).